# Can MultipartUploadRequest be used to upload a file from a FileInputStream on Android?

Tags: android, upload, multipartform-data

I'm using MultipartUploadRequest to upload files sucessfully. The file is available to my app as a FileInputStream. I'm saving the file and then uploading it. I do not need a local copy. Can I avoid making this local copy and use the FileInputStream directly? After much searching I've not found a way so perhaps there isn't.

Comment: Why would you save a file if you have already a FileInputStream? I also wonder what you would save.

Comment: If you dont have a local copy then how could there be a valid FileInputStream?